# dynamic multiple grouptext in jqgrid

Tags: dynamic, group-by, jqgrid

I have implemented multiple grouping in jqgrid which is dynamic(can be on 1 or many columns). And I want the grouptext to have a checkbox, column name and the value.

```
$("#Grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    grouping:true,
    groupingView:{
    ...
    grouptext:['<input type="checkbox" class="groupHeader"/> ColumnName: {0}']
})
```

This will give me grouptext in only one groupheader. But I can have grouping on several columns where the columnName is dynamic. I tried this which is not working:

```
var columnNames=['ABC','DEF','GHI'];
var grouptext1=['<input type="checkbox" class="groupHeader"/> columnNames: {0}'] 

$('#Grid').jqGrid('setGridParam',{grouptext:grouptext1})
```

I can change the `grouptext1` according to my needs. But I need a way to bind it to the jqGrid.

How can that be done?

Comment: Can you pleasepost your code on how you change the gruping dynamically?

Comment: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. Check "Dynamically change grouping" under "Grouping"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have a typo errr in your code. The JavaScript is case sensitive and you have write grouping text property not correct. It should be **groupText** instead of grouptext as you write.

If you can see, the groupingGroupBy method has a second parameter - options. That is exactley what you need. This parameter is a grouping options. Having this you can set the groupText. in a case you want like this

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', 
    ['col1','col2'], 
    { 
        groupText : [ 'checkbox for col1', 'checkbox for col2']
        ...
    }
);
```